# Why does Tower Law imply that $E[(X-Y)^{2}]=E[X^{2}]-E[Y^{2}]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $E[X\vert\mathcal{G}]= Y$

Why does it follow from

$$
\begin{align}
E[(X-Y)^2\mid \mathcal{G}]&=E[X^2-2XY+Y^2\mid \mathcal{G}]\\
&=E(Y^2\mid \mathcal{G})-X^2
\end{align}
$$

that the  tower law implies that
$$
E(X-Y)^2=EY^2-EX^2
$$
?

Comment: Take the expectation value on both sides of the equation... and use the tower property $$E(\dots) = E( E(\dots \mid \mathcal{G}))$$